# API from two laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I create two laravel projects. One is for backend connect with database and second project is for frontend. And then i create route API from projectone (backend project) get data from database and  pass to json. and  i want projecttwo(frontend) get the data  from api url.

i try this code:

My API route in first project:

```
Route::get('test',function(){
    $response=DB::table('student_tbl')->select('title')->get();
    return response()->json($response,200);
});
```

My Secondproject:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();        
        // Create a request
        $request = $client->get('http://localhost/myfirstproject/public/api/test');
        // Get the actual response without headers
        $response = $request->getBody();
        $json_decode=json_decode($response,true);
        foreach ($json_decode as $key => $value) {
            echo $value['title'].'<br>';
        }
```

Buti get 500 internal server error.

How to fixed this?

Comment: Take a look in the laravel.log of your api project and see if the full error message is there.

Comment: @JamesCook when i change .env secondproject database the same  with firstproject i can get the result

Comment: If I've understood your setup correctly the database configuration of your front end project shouldn't effect the responses you get from the api. Can you navigate to http://localhost/myfirstproject/public/api/test in your browser what do you get there?

Comment: yes i get all the result from my firstproject api route.

Comment: Do you have a more detailed error message for your second project than 500 internal error?

Comment: @JamesCook yes this is another error : Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#03 (truncated...)

Comment: if i change env database name different from firstproject

Comment: Ok, to clarify is that the error from the api project or second project?

Comment: I feel like this is maybe a configuration problem then. How have you got the two separate projects set up?

Comment: @JamesCook : this error is in secondproject

Comment: this two project is host in separate directory

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19454#issuecomment-305955056

based on the comment, you need to run `php artisan config:cache` to save the config for project

Comment: Thanks You Save my life. Works Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the contents from your request. Since you are receiving the API response while you are trying from the browser, it seems there can be an issue with the second project.

You have to get the `contents` before passing the value for `JSON decoding`.

```
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#03 (truncated...)

Comment: so i must configure that two project env the same??

Comment: Are you still getting the response while navigating this link in your browser? `http://localhost/myfirstproject/public/api/test`

Comment: when i configure env secondproject the same firstproject i can get data

Comment: try `dd($response)` before  this line `$json_decode=json_decode($response,true);` and what is the response? Seems like this part of the code is working fine after the above changes and something else in the second project (other than the pasted code) is breaking.

Comment: Run migrations. Base table or view not found means database was not found

Comment: then its clearly means this part is working fine. Check your other part of code or paste here where the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Base table or view not found means database was not found**

Run migrations with

```
 php artisan migrate
```

If you face other errros while running migrations then try this command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

**write your code in try catch like this:**

```
try{

  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();        
    // Create a request
    $request = $client->get('http://localhost/myfirstproject/public/api/test');
    // Get the actual response without headers
    $response = $request->getBody();
    $json_decode=json_decode($response,true);
    foreach ($json_decode as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['title'].'<br>';
    } 

 }catch(\Exception $e){

    \Log::error( $e->getMessage().' '. $e->getLine() .' '. $e->getFile());
    return $e->getMessage().' '. $e->getLine() .' '. $e->getFile(); 

 }
```

**Also,**
open your browser's developer console and open the network tab. Refresh your page and find something matching to your route in network controller. It will be red since you are getting error. click on it and see what it says. If your don't understand then just paste that response in your question

Comment: yes i got an error : Server error: `GET http://localhost/myfirstproject/public/api/test` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:

Comment: See my answer and update your second project code it will tell you the error and line no of the file.

Comment: open your browser's developer console and open the network tab.  Refresh your page and find something matching to your route in network controller. It will be red since you are getting error. click on it and see what it says. If your don't understand then just paste that response in your question

Answer (score 0):

Error code `500` basically means you have something wrong with your code. Try this turn one your application debug mode from `.env` if it is already there then its good.

Then try to hit the `api` from the browser check if that is giving /returning the response as expected. If that does then something is wrong with your 2ned project. Try to debug it same way .

The laravel error will give you a good hint where it is going wrong.